# Renaming files with perl

Tags: perl

I'm very new to perl, and I want to rename a group of files so that they are lowercase instead of uppercase (so from SBC005.wav -> sbc005.wav).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirnam = "/Users/.../SoundFiles";

opendir(DIR, $dirnam) or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);

foreach my $oldfile (@files) {
    my $newfile = lc($oldfile);
    #print $newfile;
    #print $oldfile;
    rename $oldfile, $newfile or die "Cannot rename file: $!";
    }

closedir(DIR);
```

I checked that the variables are working right with the commented out print statements, but when I run the program I get a message that says "Cannot rename file: Invalid argument at rename.pl line 13." I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Thank you so much!

edit:

Thank you so much to the answer below! I found that this code using `glob` works too, but the code below works better because it does not have to be in the same directory as the sound files (as the `glob` code does)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = glob("*.wav");

foreach my $oldfile (@files) {
    my $newfile = lc($oldfile);
    #print $newfile;
    #print $oldfile;
    rename $oldfile, $newfile or die "Cannot rename file: $!";
    }

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. you forgot to add the path of directory while  renaming.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirnam = "/Users/.../SoundFiles";

opendir(DIR, $dirnam) or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);

foreach my $oldfile (@files) 
{
    unless($oldfile  eq "." || $oldfile eq ".." )
    {           

        my $newfile = lc($oldfile);

        rename "$dirnam/$oldfile", "$dirnam/$newfile" or die "Cannot rename file: $!";
    }

}
```